# Is there OWASP ZAP docker image for windows platform?

Tags: windows, docker, owasp, docker-image, zap

The OWASP ZAP docker images are listed here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/about/

When I run the following command to pull the stable docker image on my Windows OS: `docker pull owasp/zap2docker-stable`

I get the following error:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from owasp/zap2docker-stable
image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform
```

Is there OWASP ZAP docker image for windows platform?

Answer (score 2):

The current ZAP docker images will work fine, you just need to enable switching between Windows and Linux containers: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers